# Border-radius doesn't work when background isn't applied

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Why does border-radius not work when background is not applied onto the animation.

The border radius only works when a background is applied at 0%-50%-100%. Without the background color the border-radius doesn't work.

I expect the border-radius to change from a square to a circle and then back to a square.

```css
    .square {
      /* Set up the normal state */
      display: block;
      width:350px;
      height:350px;
      margin: 200px auto;
      background:#41A9F0;
      /* apply the animation */
      animation: box 5s linear infinite;
    }
    @keyframes box {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0) scale(0.2);
        /* background: #41A9F0; */
        border-radius: 0%;
      }

      50% {
        transform: rotate(180deg) scale(2);
        /* background: #5ABE8A; */
        border-radius: 50%;
      }

      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0.2);
        /* background: #41A9F0; */
        border-radius: 0%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Shape Animation Challenge</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- HINTS
    1) Open shape-animation-ANSWER.html in your browser and try to create the final product.
    2) Create a keyframe named box.
    3) There are three points to this animation, starts off as a square, then a circle (background color for the circle is #5ABE8A), then back to a square.  
    Hint: You will need the properties border-radius and transform -->
  <div class="square"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not quite following. You can remove the background and it still works? See https://jsfiddle.net/Larfk32m/ FYI: I've set a border on the element so you would still see the element/animation.

Comment: My question is why does it not work without the background? does background set a default border that makes the border-radius work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any background color you can't see the animation but it still persist.

Here an example with your animation applied also to a div without background color but with border (to see what happen)

https://jsfiddle.net/cjohm3xb/1/

```
   .square-border {
      border:1px solid red;
      /* apply the animation */
      animation: box 8s linear infinite;
    }
```

Comment: so what im getting from this is that background does not set a border for border-radius to apply to and thus the animation persists but the border does not change because the backgorund does not include a border ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in Chrome 75.0.3770.142 and Edge 44.17763.1.0. You have provided a coloured `div`, so you can see the animation. Try to remove the background and add a child, which can be a text or something else, then you'll see the same effect. If you remove background and all the children, obviously you "will see" an empty animated `div`, which translates to nothing on screen actually!

I tried playing with keyframes, backgrounds and border radiuses. The page seems to work correctly. Check this stylesheet:

```
.square {
  /* Set up the normal state */
  display: block;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
  margin: 200px auto;
  /* apply the animation */
  background: #41A9F0; 
  animation: box 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes box {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0) scale(0.2);
    background: #41A9F0;
    border-radius: 0%;
  }

  10% {
    background: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  25% {
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 10%;
  }

  50% {
    background: red;
    transform: rotate(180deg) scale(2);
    border-radius: 30%;
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0.2);
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 0%;
  }
}
```

Remember that percentage values for border radius go from 0 to 50. Anything above 50 is simply 50.
Source: https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/559fe347e39efe4cf40005a9

I you can provide the browser you are using or explain the problem better at least, community could have provided better answers.